# How can I access/set/get a textbox string, or a public string declared in MainWindow from a UserControl?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

Context: My main window has a developer console that is hard coded into the main window to make it easier to bind the keystroke event to the main window - as such:

```
<Grid KeyDown="Grid_KeyDown"\>
    <Grid x:Name="Devloper_Console_Window" Height="250" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="500" Visibility="Hidden" \>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions\>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/\>
            <RowDefinition/\>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions\>
        <Rectangle Grid.RowSpan="2" Fill="#CC232323" Stroke="#FF232323" StrokeThickness="2"/\>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="30"\>
            <Rectangle Fill="#FF232323"/\>
            <Label Content="Developer Console" Foreground="#FF17FF00" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/\>
        </Grid\>
        <Grid  Grid.Row="1"\>
            <ScrollViewer Opacity="0.5"  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"\>
                <TextBlock x:Name="Devloper_Console"  Text="Welcome to Developer Console... &#x0a;" Margin="5" Foreground="#FF19FF0F"/\>
            </ScrollViewer\>
        </Grid\>
    </Grid\>
</Grid
```

My hope was that I would be able to set the text inside the DeveloperConsole from anywhere in the code, but I don't seem to be able to access it.

My intention is to use this as a debug window while in development and I would like to be able to log some info when events trigger an a few different areas - like in a custom UserControl like so:

```
namespace Project.CustomControls
{
    public partial class CollapsiblePanel : UserControl
    {
        public CollapsiblePanel()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Down_Button_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            // I would like to set the text in the Developer_Console here to log some information.
            // Something to get Developer_Console.Text from this spot in the code.
            Down_Icon.Fill = StaticLibrary.Brushes.White;
        }
    }
}
```

I do not have any userControl elements in my custom control that would be of use here and ideally there wont be any. The code-behind will be able to edit the content in the main window on its own.

Any help would be appreciated :)

I've tried turning my Developer_Console_Window into a custom UserControl turning it into a singleton with a publicly accessible getter/setter function to set/get the text property for the text block. (I am super green to databainding, so i didnt even try that); It didn't work out for me however. I may have implemented this incorrectly however :P If this is the route I should be following let me know, I'll give it another go.

I also implemented is just a normal custom UserControl with to no avail.

I have also tried adding a public member to MainWindow and I cannot seem to reference any public members of main window from the user control.

I am struggling simply accessing/referencing the content in the mainWindow from other controls and that's where I would like some help. Thanks

Comment: I've thought about adding a C# class that can hold all my data etc. and then just making that class accessible to everything and having the developer_console setting its contents to what the data class has every so often. Cant see why that wouldnt work, but it feels hacky and like its a work-around to a more elegant solution.

Comment: A UserControl or any other control would never directly access properties of its parent element, e.g. a Window. The control may declare a property that could be data-bound to the property of its parent element.

Comment: @Clemens So, lets say that I desire to stick to MVVM principals, If i were to go about a solution like you described: I would give the Collapsible_Panel a property lets call it 'public string myDebugText'. I would have this property declare a two-way databinding to the Developer_Console Text property? Then in a member function of Collapsible panel, if i set the property myDebugText to += "newtext" would set the Developer_Consoles TextProperty, AND  ALL other controls with two-way binding to the Developer_Console.Text? If you dont mind, can you help me understand what that would look like?

Comment: That sounds exactly like what you should do.

Comment: @Clemens - I was really hoping for some help with how that databinding would look /:

I'm not sure how to approach it. 

Example - when I create a new Binding instance in CollapsiblePanel, I cannot access anything from MainWindow, so I'm unsure how to set the source as the textbox 'Developer_Console' ...

Comment: Have tried binding to some static property ?

Comment: "A UserControl or any other control would never" - only a Sith deals in absolutes. And in a situation like this when there is a single console being used for output and, moreover, if the purpose of the developer console is solely for the UI and not for the business logic, then deviating from MVVM for something like this is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While your approach certainly works, an event would allow for MVVM-friendly separation of concerns without using a convoluted binding scheme (which I definitely would not try in this case).

In your view model (business logic) layer, declare a class like this:

```
public delegate void DevConsoleMessageHandler (string message);
public static class DeveloperConsoleViewModel
{
     public static event DevConsoleMessageHandler Message;

     public static void PostMessage(string message) 
     {
          Message.Invoke(message);
     }
}
```

Then, probably in your `MainWindow` code behind (perhaps in the constructor after `InitializeComponent()`), add:

```
DeveloperConsoleViewModel.Message += (message) => 
{
     this.Developer_Console.Text += message;
};
```

Finally, then, anywhere in your code (view model OR UI) you can simply invoke `DeveloperConsoleViewModel.PostMessage("...")`.